# Get Data entered in modal to save In Database

Tags: javascript, database, twitter-bootstrap

I am a noob in web development so I am stuck at getting data from a modal and saving it to database.
I have made model with bootstrap. Below is the code of the modal

---

### code of modal

```
    <form name="form" action="post" method="">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add part</button>
</form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add parts</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Part Name" id="pName" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Piece Code" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Piece Price" />
      <br>
      <br>

      <input type="text" name="field4" placeholder="Quatity" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field5" placeholder="Total" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field6" placeholder="Comments" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field7" placeholder="Shipped" />
      <br>
      <br>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button onclick="saveit()" type="button" name="saveBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">save</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is get the data entered in this popup modal save it in database by pressing save button in the modal and clear the pop so that user can enter data again. I want to save the data by using PHP Query .Kindly suggest me a way to get it done . I have seen a lot of tutorials and almost every question on stack overflow as well but I am unable to get it done.

Comment: first your `<form name="form" action="post" method="">` should be  `<form name="form" action="thephppage.php" method="post">`  but since i believe main reason why people use modal is to ensure the user does not suffer from page reloading. So i have given you an approach in my answer using `ajax`. I have edited some few thing to make it work. Try it and in case of anything just comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to do that; Try this

Your **contact page**

```
<div id="contact">
<h3>Contact Us For Any Query</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add part</button>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>

$(function(){
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

        var info = $("#form").serialize();  
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "add.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(result){

                //$("#form")[0].reset();
                  $('#notification').html(result); 

            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();

    });

});


</script>

<!--div for notification    -->
<div id="notification"></div>   



<div id="form" class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Add parts</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Part Name" id="pName" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Piece Code" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Piece Price" />
      <br>
      <br>

      <input type="text" name="field4" placeholder="Quatity" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field5" placeholder="Total" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field6" placeholder="Comments" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field7" placeholder="Shipped" />
      <br>
      <br>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" name="saveBtn" class="btn btn-default button" data-dismiss="modal">save</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the PHP page i.e. `add.php` for adding the data

```
<?php

    //connection to your database
    //remember to change the host, dbname, and password to yours, 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;charset=UTF-8', 
                  'root', 
                  '',
                  array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));


?>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['field1'])) {

    $field1 = $_POST['field1'];
    $field2 = $_POST['field2'];
    $field3 = $_POST['field3'];
    $field4 = $_POST['field4'];
    $field5 = $_POST['field5'];
    $field6 = $_POST['field6'];
    $field7 = $_POST['field7'];




    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7)
    VALUES (:field1, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field4, :field5, :field6, :field7)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':field1', $field1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':field2', $field2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':field3', $field3);
    $stmt->bindParam(':field4', $field4);
    $stmt->bindParam(':field5', $field5);
    $stmt->bindParam(':field6', $field6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':field7', $field7);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'added';

}

?>
```

Hope my answer would be of some help to you:

Answer (score 0):

Keep form inside modal, and give a php file(ex: test.php) as action.

Here is the code I would suggest you to try:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add part</button>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

       <form action="test.php" method="POST">
        <!-- Modal content-->
       </form>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Write a test.php file and retrieve values using $_POST method.

Comment: isn't it better to outline what has to be changed, with providing shortened code snippets and descriptions, instead of reposting the whole big code snippet?

Comment: @Farside Yes, it would be better, I did it. Thanks for suggestion :)